# get values from html select in views with django

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to get the value and even the string if possible of the selected value in my HTML file.

**index.html**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select id="drop1">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select value -- </option>
        {% for i in df %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_value = request.POST.get('drop1')
        print(selected_value)
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'df': df.designation_list})
```

With this, nothing is returned. I saw that I have to use `<form></form>` to get an html value but I can't find what to put in the `action=` field.

Can you see what is missing in my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The **action** attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.

In your case, you have to add the url of the view that will hand that data. For example:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
    <select id="drop1">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select value -- </option>
        {% for i in df %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Note: Change the `index` with the name you specified in your URL pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the index with name specified URL pattern? I've to replace it with the name of my URL app?

Comment: Edit : I specified the name in my URL pattern but it still doesn't work, I can't get the selected value